# Get the numeric part of an amount from CSS

Tags: html, css, css-variables, viewport-units, css-calc

Is there a way, using pure CSS to fetch the numeric value without pulling back the unit too?
e.g. say I have a CSS variable defined as `:root {--maxWidth: 100px;}`.  If I want to get the ratio of that value to my viewport's width I can't as `calc(100vw / var(--maxWidth))` would fail as you can't divide a number with units by another number with units; even where they're the same unit.

I can get around this example case by omitting the units from my variable (e.g. `:root {--maxWidth: 100;}`), but I'm wondering how to do this in cases where you can't.

More specifically, I want to get the ratio / conversion value for `1vw` to `1px` so that I can write code which uses `px` values, then use `transform: scale(var(--horizontalRatio), var(--verticalRatio))` to resize everything to fit perfectly in the viewport; but to do that I need a way to convert between pixels and viewport units.

There is a way to work around this; everywhere I set a size in pixels I could instead set the size to  `calc(100vw * X/var(--maxWidthInPx))` where `X` is the size in pixels of what I'm setting and `--maxWdithInPx` is a numeric only value giving the max width of the static px size.  However, that means putting these little equations everywhere, rather than just having 1 place where things get scaled.

I've found several javascript solutions for this; but I need something that's CSS only.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible with CSS. CSS styles it doesn't calculate.

Comment: I don't see how you can get round it in your example case - yes CSS wouldn't object to dividing 100vw by a number but that number would not be 100 if you really wanted to divide by 100px. You could have just one line of JS which set a CSS variable which was the viewport width in px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the near (or a far) future this will be possible using only CSS. [The specification has changed](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#calc-func) to allow the division and multiplication of different types.

You can read the following:

> At a `*` sub-expression, **multiply the types** of the left and right arguments. The sub-expression’s type is the returned result.
>
> At a `/` sub-expression, let left type be the result of finding the types of its left argument, and right type be the result of finding the types of its right argument and **then inverting it**.
>
> The sub-expression’s type is the result of **multiplying the left type and right type.**

As you can see, there are new rules that defines how types are multiplied and how the result is calculated so I am pretty sure what you want is possible but there is no implementation for this to test.

---

[The current specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#calc-type-checking) is more restrictive:

> At `*`, check that at least one side is `<number>`. If both sides are `<integer>`, resolve to `<integer>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the other side.
>
> At `/`, check that the right side is `<number>`. If the left side is `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the left side.
>
> If an operator does not pass the above checks, the expression is invalid